# Flexbox columns, wrap order bottom to top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to build a flexbox where the ordering of the elements not only start from the bottom but the last elements keeps getting pushed.

The ordering would work similar to this:

```
[3][6]

[2][5]

[1][4]
```

At present, new elements will appear at the bottom of the column.

Can this even be done with flexbox?

Comment: it's difficult to understand what are you asking. Can you provide an example with your current result and your desired result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done indeed be done with flexbox. We use the flex-direction property, to reverse the order with `flex-direction: column-reverse` and we wrap the boxes with `flex-wrap: wrap;` - This can also be done by combining the two in `flex-flow` - I've out-commented that in the pen below. What you need to take note of, is that by using columnising your boxes, you will need to add a specific height to the container. If you don't they will just keep going downwards, and not wrapping.

[Here's a pen illustrating your exact need.](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/ogOqZY?editors=110)

And the code used:

**HTML** - Notice the order.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse; /* Where ordering reverses */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrapping boxes */
    /* flex-flow: column-reverse wrap; */
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
.box { /* All properties here are for illustrative purposes */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    background-color: red;
}
```

Remember your vendor-prefixes.